# Video Chat app using portrait orientation mode on Android using Adobe AIR 3.6

Tags: android, air, adobe, android-camera

I developing a video chat app using Adobe AIR 3.6 beta on Android using the front camera.
As explained by Adobe they expect you to capture video in landscape mode.
I really need to do this in portrait mode, right now the video is 90 degrees in the wrong direction and 180 degrees in the wrong direction on the other side of my video app
I using the camera class and I fully understand that the Camera class is designed to only be used in Landscape mode.
Currenly I using the Camera and Video classes and will eventually use StageVideo!
I tried rotating the video clip using rotateX or a matrix, this works but it is still sending the video sideways in landscape mode even after I locked the mobile device in portrait. This only solves half my problem.
  I need to rotate the physical camera so The user can user can use the app in portrait mode and the video is being sent in portrait mode.  Is they ANY way to do this without having to resort to ActionScript extensions?

In Java here how to do this!

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
parameters.setRotation(90);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

How to do this in AIR and AS3.0 with both the screen and streaming video being in portrait mode?
Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sadly search for the same exactly solution. The only thing I have come up with is to also send a notification to the receiving end of the stream to let them know your device has rotated so that they can follow suit... I know painful